# Flipping through API pages

Tags: api

To Whomever It May Concern:

My name is Casey Bischel, and I'm a reporter on deadline for the Belleville News-Democrat in Southwestern Illinois. I'm trying to find a record in Senator Roy Blunt's (R-Mo.) filings, but there are 43 pages of records with 100 records apiece on them. I am new to APIs, and I need to know how I can either get all of these pages or search for the specific entity the senator gave money to. It was in 2015.

Thanks, 
Casey Bischel

Comment: This question is probably a question for the datascience.SE site, as its more to do with programming data from an open source of data than the open source of data. you havnt said where your data source is. The solution is you will need to write an R (or python, etc.) program that will call the API and retrieve the data. you can then use R, etc to search the data for what you require.

Comment: What's the link for the filings?